# How to connect to a database in openshift?

Tags: sql, openshift

I've creted a new database in openshift:

```
PostgreSQL 9.2 database added.  Please make note of these credentials:

   Root User: xxxxxxxxx
   Root Password: xxxxxxxxxx
   Database Name: xxxxxxxx

Connection URL: postgresql://$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT
```

I need to connect to the database manually via psql. How can I do that? I mean, how can I enquire that variable?

Comment: You have to read the environment variables through the mechanisms available in your programming language. Which one do you use?

Comment: @timo.rieber I use java. (JBoss javaee).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read environment variables in Java like this:

```
String envVar = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_ENV_VAR");
```

In your case:

```
String dbHost = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST");
String dbPort = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT");
```

Read more at the [Openshift docs, "Using Environment Variables"](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#reading-variable-examples).

Comment: String envVar = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_ENV_VAR");
This statement returns null value for environment.

Comment: OPENSHIFT_ENV_VAR is only a placeholder for concrete environment variables, e.g. OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST. Replace it with an existing variable name.

Comment: it still returning null , do I need to configure something before getting these value ?

Comment: Please ask another question with your specific problem.

Comment: where i have to put this argument in script or what